# How to run a capistrano task on server start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, startup

I have been thinking about this and searching this for ages without finding anything, so I am going to assume I hit the XY problem.

Let me describe my issue, this sounds common enough.

We use `capistrano` to deploy our web app and db. The relevant part is that we have a dedicated server for delayed job and we use `capistrano` to deploy to it and start/restart the processes. This is a custom number of workers with 2 different `Gemfile`s and 3 queues.

**What I want to do** is to start them up on server restart or, more to the point, on server clone + start.

**I have tried** calling `cap production delayed_job:custom_start` from the server itself.. didn't work. (This is the core of my non XY problem adjusted question). Not sure it even makes sense. But I want to know if it is possible. `custom_start` is a task that starts our set of workers.

**Alternatively** I am thinking of abstracting the code into a `rake` task or a script or something and calling it from both `capistrano` and where ever I would need to add it to start on startup. Does this make more sense?

Edit: Just found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/uYseqjkra8g).. discouraging..

p.s. I just want to clarify that when I say server I mean my Machine/ec2 instance and not my web app restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the delayed job related logic to its own script that accepts start/stop, and delegating to this script from capistrano. This means I can add this script to my rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

My Jenkins deploy jobs are littered with direct tasks developers can call such as cap dev app:fetch_logs, cap qa sanitize_environment, etc.

This feature of Capistrano is easy and verified.

What I am guessing you want to do is use Capistrano to setup rc.d files. Yes, you can do this. Should you use chef/puppet at this point? Consider. Scalr/Rightscale are funs things to look at too.

You can add a bash script as an .erb template for all your worker variables, then put upload the script into the deploy_to directory. Finally, you can setup another task (#{sudo}) to inject rc.d wrappers into rc.d. Or you rather than rc.d wrappers to you bash script, just call the bash script from rc.d-local. You can use sed to append to rc.d-local.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to add perhaps a capistrano task to rc local, but thanks

Comment: Adding a capistrano task to rc.local would probably have each server login to all the other serves in role :app and do something. I suppose you could wrap it in run_locally commands. The point being it's not the tool for rc.local. You would have to esure the box is allocated with rvm, the capistrano gem is installed correctly, /etc/profile is correct (rc.local does not run with a profile) and call full lines from rc.local (/usr/bin/cap local start_server) or some such. Way hacky and any Operations type person would shoot you.